# HTML5 SQL Callback fires before function is done

Tags: jquery, sql, html

I have been fighting with this for some time. I am using HTML5 SQL db and it seems that the success callback is firing out of time. In debug the console log from the success callback come in first then the console log for maxId. Am I wrong to assume that the success or erros callbacks would fire only after the internal function(tx, results) {} is complete?

```
webdb.getCurrentUser = function () {
            var db = webdb.db;
            var maxId = "";
            var postData = {};
            var item = "";
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM UserData", [], function (tx, results) {
                    maxId = results.rows.item(0).id;
                    console.log("max id" + maxId);
                }, webdb.okay(maxId), onerror);
            });
        }

        webdb.okay = function (t) {
            console.log("item" + t);
        }
```

Comment: `webdb.okay(maxId)` will execute `webdb.okay` immediately with the parameter `maxId`. Maybe you should move that to after the maxId console log.

Comment: I get what you are saying, so am I not understanding the concept of the success callback? How come the callback would be executed before the outcome of tx.executeSql() is known?

Comment: I believe you're passing it too many functions. `executeSql` takes 4 things: `sqlStatement, arguments, callback, errorCallback`. You're passing 5. There's only one callback. Additionally, whenever you see `functionName()`, it's evaluating the function right then, rather than passing a pointer to it.

Comment: "Am I wrong to assume that the success or error callbacks would fire only after the internal function(tx, results) {} is complete?" Yes, you are wrong. What you describe as an "internal function" IS the success callback. Also as the other guys have pointed out, there's an spurious extra parameter in the `tx.executeSql()` call.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did not notice I was using too many args. Problem solved